# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I received this error:

***System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.'***

while attempting to click the **Add** button. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;

namespace OOP_Draft
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double amount, monthlyPay, totalPay;
        int years;

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Clear();
            txtEmpno.Clear();
            txtEmail.Clear();
            txtDept.Clear();
            txtAmount.Clear();
            txtYears.Clear();
            lblPay.Text = "";
            lblTot.Text = "";
            rtxtReceipt.Clear();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if(txtName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else if (txtEmpno.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else if (txtEmail.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else if (txtDept.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else if (txtAmount.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else if (txtYears.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up the form.");
            }
            else
            {
                amount = double.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
                years = int.Parse(txtYears.Text);
                monthlyPay = amount * 0.03 / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + 0.02, years * 12));
                totalPay = monthlyPay * years * 12;
                monthly = Convert.ToString(monthlyPay);
                monthly = String.Format("{0:C}", monthlyPay);
                lblPay.Text = (monthly);
                total = String.Format("{0:C}", totalPay);
                lblTot.Text = (total);
                txtAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", amount);
            }
        }

        string monthly, total;

        private void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 10000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("prestantesi@gmail.com", "ironhide13");
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
                msg.From = new MailAddress("prestantesi@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = "Loan Receipt";
                msg.Body = rtxtReceipt.Text;
                client.Send(msg);
                MessageBox.Show("Email Sent.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlConnection con;

            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Kim\Documents\SMEMCO.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LoanRecord (Employee Name, Employee Number, Department, Loan Amount, Years To Pay, Monthly Payment, Total Payment) VALUES (@Employee Name, @Employee Number, @Department, @Loan Amount, @Years To Pay, @Monthly Payment, @Total Payment)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee Number", txtEmpno.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", txtDept.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loan Amount", txtAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Years To Pay", txtYears.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monthly Payment", lblPay.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total Payment", lblTot.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Loan Record" + "\t" + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("--------------------------------------------------------" + "\t" + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Name:" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + txtName.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Employee Number:" + "\t" + "\t" + txtEmpno.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Department:" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + txtDept.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Amount to be loaned:" + "\t" + txtAmount.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Years to Pay:" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + txtYears.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Interest Rate:" + "\t" + "\t" + lblThree.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Monthly Payment:" + "\t" + "\t" + lblPay.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("Total Payment:" + "\t" + "\t" + lblTot.Text + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("--------------------------------------------------------" + "\t" + "\n");
            rtxtReceipt.AppendText("        Official Receipt of SMEMCO      " + "\n");

        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In making the database, I watched a youtube video. I followed it step-by-step, yet I received the error. I also tried to put '"+"' in the variables but it also didn't work. My plan was when the user clicks the **Add** button, the inputted data and the calculation will be stored into the table of my database. Instead, that error pops out. What did I do wrong?

**Error message:**

[image: Error messages]

Comment: I am confident the column names with spaces are going to be a problem unless you quote them... something like “Total Payment” or [Total Payment]. FYI it is not recommended that you use spaces in DB field definitions, this is one of the reasons.

Comment: Do not use whitespace in column names / sql-parameters. (until you need to and learn howto [use them])

Comment: Thanks @JohnG and Rick. I removed the whitespaces and set the Identity specification of Id to true.

Comment: @LeyonCennedy, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can post an answer and click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer, which can help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Some unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so should be within `using` blocks. And you may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use whitespace in column names / sql-parameters. You can also try setting the Identity specification of Id parameter of your database to true.